# I have facing a issue while opening the ecllipse

Tags: eclipse

Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.
What is the issue ? could you say to me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJLMM.png)

Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.

Comment: Your Eclipse installation seems to be broken. Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select it), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. Is this a fresh installation? Have you installed a plugin or changed anything in your installation recently? If so, please provide more details.